# What is the right order of this sentence? (JLPT N2 practice question)

Tags: grammar, syntax, sentence, jlpt, word-order

From Shin Kanzen Master JLPT N2:

> 新しい店をオープンする　＿　＿　＿*　＿　かたまってきた。
>
> １　の　２　ようやく　３　にあたって　４　方針が

The right answer at the starred position is 4.

One arrangement I thought might make this answer work is:

> 新しい店をオープンするにあたっての方針がようやくかたまってきた。

However, I'm not sure if 「にあたって」 can be followed immediately by 「の」. How would this combination be interpreted then? Or maybe the right order is something else?

Comment: I would have placed things as 1.3.2.4.  I'm wondering how that is different from 1.3.4.2.

Comment: Indeed, I think the person who made this question intended オープンするにあたっての方針がようやく (3-1-4-2), but オープンするのにあたって方針がようやく (1-3-4-2) and オープンするのにあたってようやく方針が (1-3-2-4) make perfect sense to me, too. (Of course this doesn't answer why 3-1-4-2 is correct)

Comment: @naruto Thanks. I guess my main confusion in this question would be, is the の necessary here in にあたっての方針, because 方針 is a noun, and thus the の is necessary for にあたって to be able to modify it? What does this phrase, especially あたって, mean though. ("the strategy *once* new shops are opened" doesn't sound natural to me.)

Comment: @naruto I asked a Japanese teacher, and she agreed with you that "xxするのに当たってxx" sounds more grammatically correct. I guess Shin Kanzen here listed a more modern usage, which is however not necessarily the soundest in a grammatical sense.

Comment: Well, I don't know which is more modern or standard... To me, these three all sound natural and correct.

Comment: @naruto Yeah I think the objection of the Japanese teacher was focused on the fact that something that acts as a noun should precede に当たって, so the の should have been needed after the する. I guess maybe you can still implicitly assume the の even if you don't write it out explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Shin Kanzen actually gave some examples of this combination (xxするに当たってのxx, e.g. 就職するに当たっての準備), as shown in the photo. However, I asked a Japanese teacher, and she agreed with naruto in the comments, that grammatically speaking, it would be more correct to say xxするのに当たってxx, where "するの" would act as a noun, similar to "すること".

[image]

As of the meaning of the sentence, which I was confused about, "当たって" here should be interpreted as "corresponding to", i.e. "the strategy regarding the opening of new stores". Then the sentence makes sense.